# Android AsyncTask params not found

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, parameters

i am new to android / java but i have advanced knowledge in c# and .Net.

I have a problem with the AsyncTask.

My Code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class testtask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = ""; // BREAKPOINT HERE

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

And the Call:

```
public void RequestDepartments(View view) {
    BamakiWebService service = new BamakiWebService();
            RequestType request = new RequestType();

            request.Uri = "departments/all";


            try {

                testtask task = new testtask();
                task.execute("wfwef");

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Main", ex.getMessage());
            }
}
```

The Code fails because i can not access the urls?!
When i debug the doInBackground and add the urls to watch it says "Cannot find local variable 'urls'"?! ( on BreakPoint -> // BREAKPOINT HERE)

What i am doing wrong ?!

**EDIT**

Changing the Execute to

```
testtask task = new testtask();
String[] params = new String[] {"wfwef"};
task.execute(params);
```

Did not solved the Problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass a string-array! If you are passing just one string you can access that string in `doInBackground` with urls[0]! Hope it helps

```
yourAsyncTask.execute(Your URL String);
```

And in `doInBackground` access urls as like you would do with an array. urls[0]

Comment: the execute methods receives a vargs parameter, it should be the same how many string i add, or if i only add one string?

Comment: `params` is an array in asynctask. If you pass just one string it is in params at position 0. Or like in your case urls at position 0 @iOLIVER

Answer (score -1):

Give execute() a string-array as a param, not a string.
In doInBackground(String...urls)
you can get it back with urls[0], urls[1], etc.

Comment: Sorry but that dont work, i changed the execute like this

testtask task = new testtask();
String[] params = new String[] {"wfwef"};
task.execute(params);

Comment: Like execute(new String []{"your param", "your second param"})?

Comment: nope... android-studio tells mit that the explicit Array initialisation is not needed because the vargs Parameter